# How to filter R dataframes by using columns' numbers instead of their lables?

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is the toy example:

```
d1 <- data.frame(
inds = 1:8, A = c("Go", "Nah", "Nah", "Go", "Nah", "Nah", "Go", "Go"), 
B = rep("Nah", 8), C = c("Go", "Nah", "Nah", "Go", "Go", "Nah", "Nah", "Go")
)

filter(d1, A == "Go" & C == "Go")
```

So the desired output is like this:

```
inds      A        B    C
<int>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>
1        Go      Nah    Go
4        Go      Nah    Go
8        Go      Nah    Go
```

Now as you can see, I used labels of each column to define the logical condition. I need to know how can I do it by using the index (or number?) of each column.

Something in this spirit:

```
filter(d1, c(2, 4) == "Go")
```

I wish this would work, but it does not.

Tiny Update:

I got my answer, but I also needed something further that the accepted answer helped me. I thought maybe it would be useful for a few of the future viewers.

Say some of my columns ends in "_QC" and I need the index of those columns and then filter based on their values.

Thats how I did:

```
c1 <- c(grep("_QC", colnames(d1), fixed = TRUE))

filter(d1, across(c1, ~. == "Go"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `across` :

```
library(dplyr)
d1 %>% filter(across(c(2, 4), ~. == 'Go'))

#  inds  A   B  C
#1    1 Go Nah Go
#2    4 Go Nah Go
#3    8 Go Nah Go
```

---

In base R, we can use `rowSums` :

```
cols <- c(2, 4)
d1[rowSums(d1[cols] == 'Go') == length(cols), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `Reduce` from `base R`

```
subset(d1, Reduce(`&`, lapply(d1[c(2, 4)], `==`, 'Go')))
#  inds  A   B  C
#1    1 Go Nah Go
#4    4 Go Nah Go
#8    8 Go Nah Go
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option

```
> v <- c(2,4)
> setDT(d1)[, .SD[rowSums(.SD[, v, with = FALSE] == "Go") == length(v)]]
   inds  A   B  C
1:    1 Go Nah Go
2:    4 Go Nah Go
3:    8 Go Nah Go
```